# How to edit a 100GB file in Linux?

Tags: linux, files, vim

I have a file that has several times my RAM capacity and I need to edit it, search for some expressions, etc.

I've tried Vim (with LargeFiles plugin and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> trick), joe, shed all without luck.

The other option I could have it so use sed, even though by using the replace in whole file it would take a lot of time.

My file is an SQL dump, but it should work for any kind of *text*.

Any suggestions?

> NOTE: it's mandatory that it would not change file unless I command to do it, so Vim + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> trick is out of question.

Comment: Did you see this Q on askubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/questions/28847/text-editor-to-edit-large-4-3-gb-plain-text-file

Comment: @RoVo yes... the file is several times bigger than my RAM.

Comment: Are your changes something that you can represent with regular expressions?

Comment: @JeffSchaller that's what I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: Got enough disk-space for a split & merge?

Comment: @tink unfortunately no

Comment: Well ... `sed` and `regular expressions` it is then ;)

Comment: It depends on what edit you want to make. If you want replace `foo` with `bar` (replace a chunk with another one of the same length, without having to shift forwards or backwards what comes after it) -- fine. You can do it in place and without having to process the whole file. Please add those details to your question. In any case, do **not** try to load a +GB file in `vim` ;-)

Comment: Note that sed may very well copy the file to a temporary location, so if you don't have enough space for a split & merge, you may not have enough for sed.

Comment: You also can load this dump into a database, perform some migrations, run queries, and then dump it back.

Comment: I've worked with files of sizes many times larger than 100 Gb using `sed` and `awk`.  Depending on what types of things you'd like to do to the data, it's fairly easy to do so with these tools.  Unfortunately, you don't say what you want to do or what the data looks like.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: My default large file edit tool is "wxHexEditor". Using version 0.23 now. think its been updated...

Comment: What about simply using java, C, or a similar programming language?  I am fairly sure that (for example) java's buffered read/write capabilities don't require that the whole file be loaded into ram at once.  I see no reason why this task can't be accomplished via (straightforward) sequential file access.

Comment: I would get another drive, where to put temporary files, so that I could use tools, that need a temporary file (or some split file fragments). It is easy to get an extra drive with enough space: either a TB-size drive or a smaller (yet big enough) SSD, that is fast.